# Please explain what "% i*g" means in this PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, foreach, foreach-object

While working in PowerShell I needed to convert CIDR notation to IP starting address and subnet mask notation.

Performing a Google search I found [this Reddit posting challenge](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/81x324/shortest_script_challenge_cidr_to_subnet_mask/) that contained many obscure ways to perform this task.

One that I found particularly interesting was:

```
$C = 13
[ipaddress](4.GB-(4GB-shr$C))|% i*g
```

It took me a while to see that `-shr$C` was merely the PowerShell `-shr` operator without any white space before the `$C` variable reference.

I then needed to search to find that `%` is an alias for `Foreach-Object`.

By just querying the value of `[ipaddress](4.GB-(4GB-shr$C))` I received:

```
Address            : 63743
AddressFamily      : InterNetwork
ScopeId            :
IsIPv6Multicast    : False
IsIPv6LinkLocal    : False
IsIPv6SiteLocal    : False
IsIPv6Teredo       : False
IsIPv4MappedToIPv6 : False
IPAddressToString  : 255.248.0.0
```

Which showed me the properties of the IPAddress object.  The result that I need is the `IPAddressToString` property which I could get by using `%| IPAddressToString` or somehow coerce PowerShell to emit the object as a string.

Therefore, the question now is what does the syntax `% i*g` mean?

What is `i` and `g` and are we performing multiplication?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[For more examples, I'm going to refer you to my post in Programming Puzzles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111526/30402).

`%` is an alias for `ForEach-Object` which has a parameter set that accepts a property name.

You've already seen this in your use of `%| IPAddressToString`.

The parameter accepts wildcards though, so `|% i*g` means to invoke the member whose name matches that pattern, which in this case is `i` `paddresstostrin` `g`.

The pattern must resolve unambiguously, so try doing `|% i*` and you'll see an error which helpfully tells you all the members that pattern *could* match.

The reason this is not multiplication is that it's a string. Since it's a parameter to a command, the string doesn't necessarily need to be quoted.